# Wordpress facing problem with post name permalinks are not working but plain links are working after migrating website to live aws elastic beanstalk

Tags: laravel, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Wordpress facing problem with post name permalinks are not working but plain links are working after migrating website to live aws elastic beanstalk,

Everything works fine on localhost but after migrating site to live everything working fine but the postname permalinks showing 404 not found but plain links are working fine,

I have setup my wordpress in side Laravel with the name of blog folder

[Like this inside blog folder i have my wordpress setup i have also tried changing htaccess file but nothing working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpMe4.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by myself actaually the problem was i have apcahe server installed on my local machine and in live i have ngnix installed,so made some changes in ngnix conf file everything works fine now.